# Bootstrap: set height of a div relative to the height of another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying this Bootstrap example with a table in the left column and 4 columns in 2 rows in the right column. Here is the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:lavender">
    <p>Table which is hovered, stripped, bordered, contextual</p>            
     <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Default</td>
          <td>Defaultson</td>
          <td>def@somemail.com</td>
        </tr>      
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td>Primary</td>
          <td>Joe</td>
          <td>joe@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <td>Primary</td>
          <td>Joe</td>
          <td>joe@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush">
      <p>Some text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <p>Some text</p>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender">
      <p>Some text</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>Some text</p>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

It looks like this:
[image]
The left column height adjust automatically with table height, which is good. The problem is the right column does not adjust its height according to the left column. I'd like the right column height to be relative to the left column height, i.e. evenly split into 2 stacked columns, and this should be automatically adjusted according to the left column width: say I have more table rows, left column height would certainly increase but right column height should also increase and still be 50% of left column height. So it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @kukkuz edited to Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll want some flexbox magic. You could add flexbox settings to Bootstraps `row` and `col-` but that is essentially bad practice. I did some testing and in a quick code and couldn't escape this, but with more time and understanding of flexbox you could work things out. The best practice is always setting new elements and never-ever customizing any CSS of BS grid elements. That means never adding classes to elements like `.row` or `.col-` unless you're extending these components.

Explanation: The second `col-` have the right height, but its children don't (the `.row`), so you have to make the second `col-` a `flexbox` element (thus making its children know its height) and make the children (which now are flexbox items) grow (equally distributed). But again, that's not a good practice because you shouldn't temper with BS components, they have their own properties that could overlap in undesired ways.

**TL:DR**: Add `display:flexbox` to the second `col-xx-x` and make the `.row` inside it grow with `flex-grow:1`, but that should be studied for a better code standard.

[Code to working result on codepen](https://codepen.io/teefars/pen/jJVwxe)